# Migrating mongo atlas database to Azure data lake storage

Tags: mongodb, azure-data-factory, database-migration, azure-data-lake

I have a use case to migrate mongo cluster on mongo atlas to ADLS Gen 2. I setup a Azure data factory pipeline to test feasibility with 2.9GB data. It took ~18 min with average speed of 2.6MBps. Considering our entire DB is around 10TB in size this speed is not optimal and it would take weeks for the migration
[image]

My question is:

- Is there a faster way of migrating. It doesn't have to be using data
  factory, I simply searched for options and decided to try it out with
  ADFS and am open to other tools if the performance is better
- In ADFS
  I notice one needs to specify collection. But I would be interested
  in just specifying the database so the copy option will copy all
  collections. Is that option supported or specifying collection is
  mandatory?

EDIT:
I updated DIU and parallelCopies attribute but it didn't make any difference to the total time
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the [Copy performance optimization feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-optimization-features) to enhance the performance of migration process.

The below image shows the achievable performance.

[image]

Also refer [Performance tuning steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#performance-tuning-steps).

If alone DIU and ParallelCopy not working, you need to use a more powerful compute environment, i.e., Azure IR.

Create a new Azure IR by following this tutorial: [create and configure Azure Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory). **Make sure your Region should be near to your stored data location.** Under **Compute type** use ***Memory Optimized*** and **Core count** would be ***16 ( + 16 Driver cores)*** or more.

See the below image for your reference.

[image]

Use this newly created IR to run your pipeline. This should work.

Comment: I did change the DIU and parallelCopies but it kinda didn't have any effect. Hmm there's no way to add screenshots in comments

Comment: If that's the case, you must be using the default Azure IR compute (General purpose, 4 Driver cores). you should create a new Azure IR with memory optimized and higher cores (16 or 32) to get the desired output. Follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory. Updating my answer also.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to create new IR with higher specs and associate it to the source and sink linked services.  Post that I changed the DIU to 8 and parallelCopies to 4 in copy activity. And publish. Yet a debug run took DIU as 4 and parallelCopies as 1. I'm inclined to think its something to do with the source and sink type limitation specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#data-integration-units) under the heading **From non-file store to file store**

Comment: There's similar info for parallelCopies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features#parallel-copy) stating _For other scenarios, parallel copy doesn't take effect. Even if parallelism is specified, it's not applied._